# Restore contents of changed file

Tags: file, text, restore

in an important file I am missing most of what I have written. I must have accidentally pressed ctrl+a, then written my new stuff and saved it or anything. I can't explain it to me.

I am using windows and ubuntu on that machine. The .txt file is on the windows partition but I most probably edited it with gedit from ubuntu. I don't know if what I described what supposedly has happened to the file would count as 'overwrite' ?

Would there be any method of restoring it?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a post suitable for superusers.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, see whether the editor has kept any backup files, like `#yourfile#` or `yourfile~` or `yourfile.bak` or `.yourfile.bak` or anything of the sort. Failing that, go to the Ubuntu machine and see whether the editor instance is still running. If so, you may be able to just use the undo command in the editor. Failing that, pull a copy from your last night's backup. Otherwise, not a chance.